# exc_bad_access when using Mat in OpenCV although it looks like my indexes are correct

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv, exc-bad-access

I develop some algorithm on Mac using Xcode 5 and OpenCV. I do it as C++.

I define matrix:

```
Mat src;
int cols = 560;
int rows = 260;
src.create( cols, rows, DataType<double>::type);
```

In the code I have a loop looks like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<src.rows; i++) {
        const double* srcIterator = src.ptr<double>(i);
        for (int j=0; j<src.cols; j++) {
            double temp = srcIterator[j];
            temp++;
        }
    }
```

I read the function that has this loop for every frame I read. Most of the times it runs correctly (it is running in endless loop and it always ok).

In some runs I get exc_bad_access error. When it happened it happened for the first frame.
The error is on the line: double temp = srcIterator[j];

When it happened j is much bellow 560 and alway above 500, but each time it has a deferent value.

I thought may be I mix the cols and rows but if it was right I would get this error when j was 260 (the size of rows).

Please, Anyone has any guess what can it be?

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-create), you seem to have inverted the rows and columns parameters in the call to `cv::Mat::create()`.
This would also explain that you get an invalid access when you try to read with large values for i and j.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

It seems that not this is the problem for some resins:

1. In my question I wrote the cols and rows in create not as it is in my code. In my code is written correctly.

2. Even this was the way I wrote it, the loops are run on crd.cols and src.rows. So I may get some other errors but not the one I'm talking about right now.

Comment: Try running your code in the desktop (either as a mac command line app or in the simulator) with the valgrind memchecker. It should point you right to your faulty line.